# bat file to open some cmd prompt in different windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to write bat file to open new different cmd windows.
what I have now it's each code in different file and I want to merge this code to be in one file.

file1.bat

```
    @ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe /k  "cd \ && cd Program Files\MongoDB\server\3.6\bin && mongod.exe --dbpath /Users/XXXX/mongo-data 
&& exit"
```

file2.bat

```
    @ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe /k  "cd \ && cd Program Files\MongoDB\server\3.6\bin && mongo.exe
&& exit"
```

file3.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
start cmd.exe /k  "cd \ && cd Users\XXX\Documents\Projects\te\pn && npm start && exit"
```

Comment: why `cd \ ` then `cd Program Files\MongoDB\server\3.6\bin` separately? Why don't just `cd \Program Files\MongoDB\server\3.6\bin`, or better yet `cd %programfiles%\MongoDB\server\3.6\bin`. Same to `%USERPROFILE%` instead of `Users\XXX`

Comment: how can I merge all the code for one piece code?

Comment: I would suggest that you should try the commands without changing working directories, using `Start` or running the executables as arguments to `cmd.exe`. `@"%ProgramFiles%\MongoDB\server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath "%UserProfile%\mongo-data"`   `@"%ProgramFiles%\MongoDB\server\3.6\bin\mongo.exe"`   `@Call "%UserProfile%\Documents\Projects\te\pn\npm.cmd" start`. If it failed to work as intended, I would modify the commands from that base. Were it necessary to run them as arguments to `Cmd.exe` I would question using `cmd /k` with an explicit `exit`, when it seems `Cmd /C` appears more suited.

Comment: @compo: `cmd /c` closes the window. `cmd /k` together with `&& exit` does close it *if successful* (leaving it open for reading errors when failed). Small but nice difference.

Comment: @Stephan, if that is indeed the purpose, then perhaps `Cmd /C` with `|| Pause` would be a better choice, unless of course the command is more prone to failure that success, _and if that was the case, I'd get rid of it!_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start` has a switch to give it a working folder, so there is no need to do it inside the new instance:

```
start /d "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\server\3.6\bin" cmd.exe /k  "mongod.exe --dbpath /Users/XXXX/mongo-data && exit"
```

but it should be possible to just:

```
start /d "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\server\3.6\bin" "" mongod.exe --dbpath /Users/XXXX/mongo-data
```

where `""` is a pseudo window title (`start` takes the first quoted argument as a window title; the path does not count, because it's a parameter to the `/d` switch)

Your complete script could look like:

```
@ECHO OFF
start /d "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\server\3.6\bin" "" cmd.exe /k "mongod.exe --dbpath /Users/XXXX/mongo-data && exit"
start /d "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\server\3.6\bin" "" cmd.exe /k "mongo.exe && exit"
start /d "C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Projects\te\pn" "" cmd.exe /k "npm start && exit"
```

Comment: and how I add the other commands? can you show me with me code, to merge it together please

Comment: @AdirZoari then just copy the other lines to a single file using this logic. You can even chain them if you want.

Comment: not quite. Your last line is correct, for the first two, move the `&& exit` up to the end of the line(s) before.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm looking for @Stephan. thank you. what /d do?

Comment: It gives a Working Folder 
See Start /?